# How an object is removing duplicates?

Tags: javascript

I am new to object oriented coding. I found this example when practising.

It is confusing; whenever we are passing an array to a function it is removing the duplicates.

I wondered where are the duplicated values,how they are gone and how it is sorting the array?

Can any one explain me in deeply. I am new to object oriented concepts.

```js
function duplicate(arr) {
  var i, len = arr.length,
    obj = {};
  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    obj[arr[i]] = 0;
  }
  return obj;
}
//calling function
console.log(
  duplicate([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, 10, 100])
);

// result::{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 10: 0, 100: 0, -1: 0}
```

Comment: Object always have unique keys, What this function does is setting each array value as key of the object and each time and new key is added to object it will override the previous one (if it exist before) thats why you dont see any duplicated key in object

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: However the code is not interesting. It would have been more clever if it had counted the dupes instead of just setting them to 0.
The code above should use a map or a filter. Even just an array indexOf  would be better

Comment: Like this `function deduplicate(arr) {
  var out = [];
  for (i = 0, len=arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (out.indexOf(arr[i])==-1) out.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return out;
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a strange way to do it but I've commented the code to make it easier to understand.

```js
function duplicate(arr) {
  // declare variables 
  var i, len = arr.length,
    obj = {};

  // for each item in the array
  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    // create or set key within obj named the current array item with the value 0
    obj[arr[i]] = 0;
  }

  // return the created object
  return obj;
}
//calling function and passing the array
console.log(duplicate([1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, 10, 100]))
```

This works because when the key is set it is unique so calling again will edit the existing entry and not add another.

A quick way to make this better would be to return just the object keys rather than the whole object. You'd do this by changing `return obj;` to `return Object.keys(obj);`

Comment: Thanks for the response, i understood that object contains only unique keys, but how sorting works here. Is there any mechanism, thanks in advance.

Comment: it's just displaying it with an alphanumeric sort, there is not sorting happening in the background.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that each key is a string so you lose the option to sort them as numbers.